# Impulse response function interpretation

Tags: volatility, statistics, standard-deviation, vector-autoregression

I would need a quick help with Impulse response function interpretation which I have done after Vector autoregression model in stata.

I need to understand **how to interpret IRF graph or table values correctly**. What does the value on y axis mean?

In am trying to understand **response of Exchange rate volatility to Interest rate** (both values are in log differences). Possible interpretations when there is **0.001 spike** visible:

- 1 standard deviation shock in IR cause 0.001 change to ER volatility value
- 1 standard deviation shock in IR cause 0.1% change to ER volatility
- 1 standard deviation shock in IR cause change to ER volatility of 0.001 of shock size
- any other explation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An impulse response shows after a variable A has been shocked by 1 standard deviation, how the other variables respond to the shock.

Eg. when there is 0.001 spike visible for variable B
 1 standard deviation shock to variable A cause 0.1% change to variable B